# Transform memory nodes to JSON

Tags: json, nosql, xquery

I need to transform der memory node to JSON. Expected output:

```
{
    "citations": [
        {
            "cited": "classes",
            "procceding": [
                "applied",
                "considered",
                "followed"
            ]
        },
        {
            "cited": "toCase",
            "procceding": [
                "Ty Corp Ltd v Nu Inc",
                "PY Arbitrage v Bank of WN"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

My XQuery:

```
let $nodes :=
<cases>
  <citations>
    <classes>
      <text>applied</text>
      <text>considered</text>
      <text>followed</text>
    </classes>
    <toCase>
      <text>Ty Corp Ltd v Nu Inc</text>
      <text>PY Arbitrage v Bank of WN</text>
    </toCase>
  </citations>
</cases>
return     
let $map := map:map()
let $p :=
    for $node in $nodes/citations/node()
    let $nodeName := local-name($node)
    let $c :=
      map:put($map, "citations", map:new(map:entry('cited', map:new(map:entry($nodeName, (for $value in $node/node() return $value/fn:string(.)) ))) )  )
    return $c
return xdmp:to-json($map)
```

`$nodes` is wrongly transformed:

{"citations": {"cited": {"toCase": ["Ty Corp Ltd v Nu Inc", "PY Arbitrage v Bank of WN"]}}

How can I get the expected JSON?

Comment: Your requirement is straightforward, though uncommon. `map:new map:entry` will not work in your case. You can use `json:array-push` into `json:array` , preferably packaged in functions(s).  Give yourself some time to learn the ropes, come back if you still can’t resolve the problems…

Comment: @FionaChen: -) I tried `let $value-array := json:array() let $v := for $value in $node/node() return json:array-push($value-array, $value/fn:string(.)) return $value-array` And the result is getting much worse. No, I can’t work it out. Can you?  -) Since you and James disapprove the way I worked with JSON, can you give an example of how and what xml to json?   -) Can XSLT get the transformation done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

--) You can use json:object() to scaffold in-memory JSON model ( equivalent of XML schema ) and preserve the Object order. I refactor and streamline one of my xml-to-json modules as below. It should fulfill your needs.

```
declare function local:marshal-json(
  $master-node as node()
) as item()
{
  let $master-object := json:object()
  let $_ :=
    for $child-node in $master-node/node()
    let $child-name := local-name($child-node)
    return
      map:put($master-object, $child-name,
          for $floor in $child-node/node() return local:floor-object($floor)
      )      
  return $master-object        
};

declare function local:floor-object(
  $child-node as node()  
) as item()
{
  let $floor-object := json:object()
  let $_ := map:put($floor-object, "cited", local-name($child-node))
  let $floor-values := json:array()
  let $_ :=
    for $gc in $child-node/node()
    return json:array-push($floor-values, $gc/fn:string(.))
  let $_ := map:put($floor-object, "procceding", $floor-values)  
  return
    $floor-object  
};

let $nodes :=
<cases>
  <citations>
    <classes>
      <text>applied</text>
      <text>considered</text>
      <text>followed</text>
    </classes>
    <toCase>
      <text>Ty Corp Ltd v Nu Inc</text>
      <text>PY Arbitrage v Bank of WN</text>
    </toCase>
  </citations>
</cases>
return 
  local:marshal-json($nodes)
```

--) I am not in a position to disapprove over your design. But I approve the spirit.
You should be able to transform the XML to JSON (with parameters not hardcoded JSON names) using **similar** logic.

Example: Transform

```
<investment>
    <entity>
        <name>XYZ</name>
    </entity>
    <bogus>encrypted</bogus>
    <property>
        <Canadian>
            <propertyType>eligible dividend of CPC</propertyType>
            <notionalAmount>10000</notionalAmount>
        </Canadian>
        <foreign>
            <propertyType>dividend of trust</propertyType>
            <notionalAmount>7000</notionalAmount>
            <foreignWithholding>660</foreignWithholding>
        </foreign>
    </property>
    <capital>
        <portfolio>
            <name>HF25</name>
            <inadequateConsiderationFMV>10000</inadequateConsiderationFMV>
            <transferredAmount>15000</transferredAmount>
            <gainLossOnDisposition>11000</gainLossOnDisposition>
        </portfolio>
        <portfolio>
            <name>UL1</name>
            <superficialLoss>17000</superficialLoss>
            <reacquired>5000</reacquired>
            <gainLossOnDisposition>-2000</gainLossOnDisposition>
        </portfolio>
        <security-CUSIP1>
            <gainLossOnDisposition>-3600</gainLossOnDisposition>
        </security-CUSIP1>
    </capital>
</investment>
```

to JSON:

```
{
    "entity": {
        "name": "XYZ"
    },
    "bogus": null,
    "property": {
        "Canadian": {
            "propertyType": "eligible dividend of CPC",
            "notionalAmount": 10000
       },
        "foreign": {
            "propertyType": "dividend of trust",
            "notionalAmount": 7000,
            "foreignWithholding": 660
        }
    },
    "capital": {
        "portfolio": [
            {
                "name": "HF25",
                "inadequateConsiderationFMV": 10000,
                "transferredAmount": 15000,
                "gainLossOnDisposition": 11000
            },
            {
                "name": "UL1",
                "superficialLoss": 17000,
                "reacquired": 5000,
                "gainLossOnDisposition": -2000
            }
        ], 
        "security-CUSIP1": {
            "gainLossOnDisposition": -3600
        }
    }
}
```

I use low-level APIs with more leverage: It transforms XML string/text to JSON `string` or `number` upon instructions; It conforms to the customised JSON model, object and array structure; It observes XML/JSON naming convention in financial domain.

--) That said, this programming model is memory-intensive. If XSLT3 parses and transforms JSON in streaming model in Java, it could be more memory-efficient. I never use XSLT3 JSON parser as now and can’t comment on its efficacy.

Comment: It is working perfect now!  This is very helpful for me to understand the logic.  BTW, You mentioned json:transform-json can transform the xml to JSON. No?

Comment: As a tactical approach (e.g. The client has such business requirements), I use `json:transform-from/to-json` whenever possible. Once the utility and narrative pivot, I prefer low-level API despite its ‘lowness’ as strategic approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
let $nodes :=
  <cases>
    <citations>
      <classes>
        <text>applied</text>
        <text>considered</text>
        <text>followed</text>
      </classes>
      <toCase>
        <text>Ty Corp Ltd v Nu Inc</text>
        <text>PY Arbitrage v Bank of WN</text>
      </toCase>
    </citations>
  </cases>
return     

let $citations := 
  for $node in $nodes/citations/node()
  let $nodeName := local-name($node)
  return 
    map:new(( 
      map:entry('cited', $nodeName), 
      map:entry("procceding", for $value in $node/node() return $value/fn:string(.) )
    ))   
return 
  map:entry("citations", $citations) => xdmp:to-json()
```

Comment: You don't need the "array-node" wrappers. Sequences will get converted to arrays in JSON.

Comment: Thanks @JamesKerr I was using `array-node` from @Chris other question, where it did matter to ensure order and had just applied without testing. Updated to just set the sequence of values.

Comment: Thanks, @MadsHansen! Your code produces sequences like: `{"procceding": […], "cited": "classes"}` But `cited` must before `procceding`. The order of the JSON properties/values is very important. I arrange your code in different way to get the correct sequence but no luck.

Comment: Order of JSON properties should not matter. jSON is a map. If you care about order, maybe XML serialization would be better. Or, downstream customers that care should use better tooling.

Comment: Yes, I care about the JSON order very much. Can you show an example of your XML serialization or tooling?

Comment: Why do you care about the order? What tools or API are you reading the output where the order matters?

Comment: Per @MadsHansen, the JSON spec https://www.json.org/json-en.html says "An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs." If you want order in JSON, you have to use arrays. Given your example, I'm curious as well why you would need the "cited" property to appear before the "proceeding" property in an object.

Comment: I can give you two out of many obvious reasons. -) When there is conditional node insert, update, merge after the `cited` node, where/what is that after disordered `cited` node? It is blank as your answer currently stands. -) The order is maintained so I can transform more complex XML. I am looking at example ML function as it is very different from W3C Xquery 3. I hope I make my points clear.

Comment: You can't really think about JSON like that as, per the spec, the properties have no guaranteed order. You can either switch to use XML which does have order for elements or you can implement a JSON structure that uses arrays to order your properties in the way you want them. @MadsHansen or I can post an example to create XML instead.

Comment: Do you have an example to use arrays to order the properties?

Comment: You can just change the `map:new(( ` line to ` map:new(map:entry('citation', (` to get the `cited` and `proceeding` properties to be their own objects in an array instead. I'm not sure if that is really what you want though. I wouldn't want to work with JSON like that.

Comment: @FionaChen, can you please help? Thanks!

Comment: @MadsHansen and JamesKerr:  Thanks for all the help!